# Is Row(EA) = Row(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have a square matrix A and an Elementer matrix E with the same ordo as A, can we say that Row(EA) = Row(A)?

I found this isn't true, because of a counter example of

A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}

we will have Row(A) = {(1,2),(3,4)}

and if we have,

E = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}

we will have

EA = \begin{bmatrix}3&4\\1&2\end{bmatrix}

we have  row(EA) = {(3,4),(1,2)}

is that enough of a counter example?
But if we use the echeleon form of the matrices then we can say that Row(EA) = Row(A) because both are {(1,0),(0,1)}
so which one is true?

Comment: what does Row mean? the set of rows of a particular matrix? what does ordo mean? why are you performing $AE$ rather than $EA$?

Comment: If you're reading about this in some book surely $Row(A)$ is not the set of rows of $A$, as you seem to think - in fact $Row(A)$ is the _rowspace_ of $A$, which is to say the _span of_  the rows of $A$. With that definition then yes, $Row(A)=Row(EA)$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that matrix is not commutative. $AE \neq EA$.

Also, elementary row operations doesn't change the row space of $A$.

Hence if Row refers to the rowspace, then we have $\operatorname{Row}(A)=\operatorname{Row}(EA)$.

Notice that $AE$ correponds to elementary column operation, elementary column operation might change the row space in general.

Comment: sorry, edited just now, thank you

Comment: Notice that your $Row(EA)$ is wrong. Also, does $Row$ indicate row space?